# Jersey initialization code after webapp is fully started

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I asked this question earlier:
[Jersey app-run initialization code on startup to initialize application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424465/jersey-app-run-initialization-code-on-startup-to-initialize-application)

Is there any way to run this initialization code after the server has initialized the web app fully ? I am running into a catch-22 problem in that I need the web app fully started by Tomcat before I can run my login call once ?

Comment: It sounds like you should be rethinking your design...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few considerations. First, Jersey is implemented as a servlet, and that's how it gets loaded. The simplest way to decouple servlet startup from servlet context startup is to not load it on startup. Accomplish this by omitting the load-on-startup element from the servlet descriptor in the web.xml. Setting it to a non-positive should also work.

If you *must* load the servlet on startup but still want to decouple it, which was my case, you'll probably have to write some custom code, which I did. I couldn't think of any other way. Use a listener of some type--a [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) or Spring [ApplicationListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html), depending on exactly how your app is set up--to kick off a new thread that will initialize your Jersey servlet by making an HTTP request to it. It feels a little dirty, but like I said, it's the only thing I and my team could come up with.

Comment: I ended up doing it with a ServletFilter that made the call on the 1st request and not on other calls.