# Jersey (javax.ws.rs): how to do initialisation at page level ONLY not at application level

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0, javax.ws.rs, spring-jersey

I need to do a lot of initialisation for few pages when they are called for only first time. Here is a decent post that addresses this: [Initialize database on Jersey webapp startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875682/initialize-database-on-jersey-webapp-startup)

But the problem with the above approach is that the initialisation is done at application level which I don't want. I am not sure if and when a particular page will be called and so I want to go with initialisation only when the page is called for the first time.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this when using jersey. (Spring has @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy for this purpose at controller/page level... so some thing similar is what I need).  A small example or code will help greatly.

Comment: Jersey 1.x and 2.x have different capabilities. Please choose the correct tag for the version you actually intend to use. And why the spring-jersey tag? Are you actually integrating Spring with Jersey?

Comment: Right, I am using both 1.x and 2.x on separate projects plus I will integrate with spring

Comment: If you are integrating Spring and it is handling the lifecycle of your resources, then the Spring annotations you mentioned should work as desired.